# With setResponsePage, how can I add the page version of the page I want?

Tags: wicket

With `setReponsePage`, how can I add the page version of the page I want? So for example 3 in http://localhost:8080/wicket-testing/?3.

Thanks.

Comment: You know you did something wrong if your question contains essentially your title and nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `#setResponsePage(Page)` instead, not `#setResponsePage(Class)`.

First you need to get a reference to the page with that id: `session.getPageManager().getPage(pageId)`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you confusing wicket pages (where the constructor does not need a wicket-id) with panels (where you have to provide a wicket-id)?

`setResponsePage` itself accepts either a class (with optional PageParameters) or an instance as a parameter:

```
setResponsePage(DestinationPage.class);
setResponsePage(DestinationPageWithPageParameters.class, new PageParameters().add("id", 42));
setResponsePage(new DestinationPageWithConstructorParameters(param1, param2));
```

If you are talking about panels (e.g. MyPanel(String wicketId)) then you need to embed this panel into a wicket page because you cannot pass a panel to `setReponsePage`.

Comment: No, See Chapter 8 in the manual. It is the version number of the page, for example 3 in /?3.

Comment: Ah ok, you asked first for the "page id" instead of "page version" that's why I thought you were confusing things. But Martin gave you in the meanwhile already the answer to your question.

Comment: In the wicket source code the name is indeed: page id. There is no confusion because as you said a page does not have a id.